# Can't see what I type in Excel cells until I hit enter

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I type in any of the cells of one Excel workbook the characters don't show in the cell until I hit enter.  All other Excel workbooks I have show the characters as I type them.  This workbook is based on a template workbook I created.  The characters show up as I type in that original workbook as well.  How can I change this so the characters show in the cells as I type them?

Comment: Sorry but your explanation is unclear and I don't understand what you are experiencing. Can you show some screenshots or/and better explain whats going on?

Comment: See [Blank cells - until I press enter!](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/blank-cells-until-i-press-enter/9ad73990-15f7-41b1-bc0c-a48af23bd9b7)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is some Protection on your templated Worksheet.

Here is a link displaying what I guess you are seeing: http://www.lytebyte.com/2009/07/01/how-to-hide-and-unhide-formulas-in-excel/

[image: hidden formula]

Try to Unprotect your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if the Font is set to Calibri (body). Not sure why but just change to a different font and you should be fine - works for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although this might've solved your issue, it's definitely not a general solution. I'm using calibri font since a long time ago and never faced this issue.